# On representable abelian sheaves vs abelian sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, schemes, abelian-categories, abelian-schemes

Let $S$ be a scheme, $(\text{Sch}/S)_{\rm Ét}$ a big étale site, and $A$ a representable
(either in schemes or algebraic spaces over $S$) **abelian** sheaf on $(\text{Sch}/S)_{\rm Ét}$.

Suppose there is a short exact sequence of abelian sheaves on $(\text{Sch}/S)_{Ét}$:

$$0\to A_1\to A\to A_2\to 0.$$

> - Are $A_1$ and $A_2$ representable?
> - are the maps $A_1\to A$ and $A\to A_1$ representable, the former by a closed immersion?

If both maps are representable, then $A_1$ is representable if and only if $A_2$ is.

Conversely:

> if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are representable, is $A$ too?

In other words, is the full subcategory of the category of abelian sheaves on $(\text{Sch}/S)_{Ét}$ given by representable abelian sheaves and morphisms/representable morphisms of abelian sheaves, a weak Serre subcategory?

Comment: I don't see your "clearly one is representable if and only if..." If by representable you mean representable by a group object in the category of scheme/S then any discrete group is representable, and I can look at thing very far from geometry like the quotient of $GL_n$ by the discrete group of points $GL_n(S)$.